# Eclipse CDT C++ - [Main] program not specified

Tags: c++, eclipse, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

Hi This is my first time working with C++ on eclipse. I'm using cygwin. 
I'm just trying to create a simple hello world program. The build is successful but when I try to run, it says "launch failed. binary not found".

In settings which I check the run configuration, there's nothing listed on clicking "search project..". Am I doing something wrong?

Would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably found your solution, but here's for anyone else who might have the same problem:

- **If you want to use cygwin toolchain** then you'll have to build a makefile first, and then build your project. You can follow the official guide here: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp (C/C++ Development User Guide >> Getting Started >> Creating a Makefile project)
- **If you don't mind changing the cygwin toolchain**: The fastest way to build and run a C/C++ project would be to create another project, this time un-ticking the show project types and choose as MINGW GCC toolchain (check 1st image below). After you create your project, you just right click on project and choose the rebuild option (check 2nd image below).

  [image]

[image]